# Nginx rule restricting particular page to render only on private ip

Tags: proxy, nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I'm using keycloak and it is running on public ip and admin console also accessible via public ip and I'm using nginx web server.
I have a requirement that the admin console should be accessible only on private ip. Other URL's should work normally on public ip/domain name.

Now, 
Ex: **domain_name/auth** and **domanin_name/auth/realm/admin** and other urls is accessible publicly.

Requirement: Only this admin console **domanin_name/auth/realm/admin** url should be accessible only through private ip.

Can this be done through nginx rules?

Please anyone help me on this.

Below is the configuration which I'm trying but it is not working as expected.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8880;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }

    location /auth/realms/master {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your nginx config please?

Comment: updated question @SamuelP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple server entries and `allow` and `deny` as you already did:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location /auth/realm/admin {
        deny all;
        ...
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your-private-ip>;

    location /auth/realm/admin {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That rule will allow to open particurlar directive/page when connected to that network/ip address. But I want that page to rendered on private ip no matter to which network/ip address that I'm using.

Comment: You don't have access to the private ip behind a nat. Or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: Seems question is not clear I guess. For security reasons I don't want to allow that admin console to publicly accessible and I don't even want restrict for allow for particular public ip's. Basically the admin console should open only with <private_ip>/auth/admin

Comment: Ok, now I got it.

Comment: I think I found the solution. By redirecting the <domain_name>/auth/admin to <localhost>/auth/admin. @Samuel P
    
**location /auth/admin/ {
    return 301 http://localhost:8880/auth/admin/;
}**

Comment: I would not do that, because every public request is redirected to localhost, which does not exist. I updated my answer and hope it helps now.

Comment: Thanks samuel. Better way to do it.